# How to get buttons to get a function to return something?

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

Python has the very useful lambda function, which I am using in a button, but I need it so that when the button is pressed it makes the main function return a string (or boolean), let us say True.

Here is an example code:

```
from tkintet import *

def buttonwindow():
    tk = Tk()
    button = Button(tk, text = "Press Me!", commmand = lambda : return True)
    button.pack() 
print (buttonwindow())
```

but before it can even get to print, Python indicates that there is a bug in the code at the end of the word return. I think it might be because `return True` is doing so for the lambda (which I don't want anyway, because I need `buttonwindow()`, not the lambda, to return True) , maybe a function which lambdas cannot do.

Does anyone know how I could get it so that `buttonwindow()` returns true. I have already tried using no lambda (e.g: `...command = return True)` fails aswell. Using lambdas is probably the wrong idea but I need to know what the right idea is. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: A called function can't make its caller do anything.  However, perhaps your problem is that you need `lambda: True`.  A lambda holds a single expression whose value is automatically returned, so you don't need (and can't use) `return` inside it.

Comment: @BrenBarn This doesn't seem to get the function, buttonwindow() to return True (I think it might just return true to the button command). As I said in the question, I am not exactly sure but lambdas might be the wrong way of looking at it?

Comment: As I said, a function cannot force its caller to return.  Your code has additional errors (what is that `=` doing after `button.pack()`?) and there's no clear reason you'd even want `buttonwindow()` to return True anyway.

Comment: I think that your design is flawed. Event handlers are designed to handle asynchronous *events*, but you're attempting to use them in a synchronous manner. Try to think of the program as a bunch of separate parts that pass messages at to each other at unpredictable times instead.

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry, = was there by accident. The above is an example of a code I need, so it might be more applicable to other situations of anyone else who might be asking a similar question. In this example, I need buttonwindow() to return True because if the button is pressed then True will be printed out. I know that this could be accomplished with lambdas `... command = lambda : print(True)`, but other cases it can't be. Does this clear up the equals thing (a mistype by me) and the requirement for a return of true, (in this case in order to print it out), or am I being more confusing?

Comment: @JoelCornett Any Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core question you seem to be asking is "Does anyone know how I could get it so that buttonwindow() returns true"

The answer to that is to better understand how tkinter works, and then craft a solution using that knowledge. You can't get there by figuring out how to get lambda to return true. The problem is much deeper than a couple lines of code can solve.

If you're trying to create a function that opens a window and waits for user input before returning, you need to do a couple of things. First, you need to make sure you run the event loop after creating your widget(s). You then need to create a callback function that sets a value somewhere accessible to the main function. Next, you need to have the callback function stop the event loop after the user enters their data. Finally, you need to get that data and return it after the event loop stops.

The easiest way is to create a class, so that you can use an instance variable to pass data around. Following is a working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        self.root = None

    def show(self):
        '''Show the window, and wait for the user to click a button'''

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        true_button = tk.Button(self.root, text = "True", 
                                command= lambda: self.finish(True))
        false_button = tk.Button(self.root, text = "False", 
                                 command= lambda: self.finish(False))

        true_button.pack()
        false_button.pack()

        # start the loop, and wait for the dialog to be
        # destroyed. Then, return the value:
        self.root.mainloop()
        return self.value

    def finish(self, value):
        '''Set the value and close the window

        This will cause the show() function to return.
        '''
        self.value = value
        self.root.destroy()


print("getting ready to show dialog...")
print("value:", Example().show())
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Why there's a "bug" at `return`

A `lambda` function implicitly `return`s the value of the evaluated expression, so explicitly using `return` is superfluous, and (as you have discovered) illegal in Python.

Therefore, the `lambda` function:

```
lambda: "foo"
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def equivalent_function():
    return "foo"
```

#### How to get "True" to print to stdout

If you simply want to print `True` to `stdout`, you can do:

```
def my_callback():
    print(True)

button = Button(tk, text="Press Me!", command=my_callback)
```

If you are using Python 3.x, then `print` is just a regular function, called with parentheses, and you can use a `lambda` function with no problems:

```
button = Button(tk, text="Press Me!", command=lambda: print(True))
```

However, if you are using Python 2.x, `print` is a *statement* (like `return`), and using it in a `lambda` function will raise an error. You *can* use the Python 3.x `print` *function* in Python 2.x by including the following import at the top of your script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```